# Install pods for Today Extension(Widget) in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, widget, cocoapods, today-extension

How can I install pods for an extension also named as Widget in my app. I'm already having that pod installed for my app target.

I've looked online and the solution that I found has got me errors like one in the screenshot.

[image]

Following is the code in my pods file:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'myapp' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.8.0'
end

target 'myapp_extension' do
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.8.0'
end



Multiple commands produce '/Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-hitzznvtnviylfcammkfaxjvlryg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app/Frameworks/nanopb.framework':
1) That command depends on command in Target 'myapp' (project 'myapp'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
2) That command depends on command in Target 'myapp' (project 'myapp'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
```

Comment: Could you share the original error / podfile you have? Since the podfile you've posted seems to be correct.

Comment: @nrx Podfile is same as I've shown to you only some more pods are there in 'myapp' target. I've wrote the error In question. Also I'm getting this error 21 times means one for each pods framework.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `inherit! :search_paths` to add same pods to your extensions

```
platform: ios, '9.0'

target 'myapp' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.8.0'

    target 'myapp_extension' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end

end
```

Comment: But I'm still getting the same error as given in screenshot.

Comment: Can you share the actual pod file?

Comment: In my case, I was adding the pods both in the main target and in the extension target. That caused the "multiple commands produce..." error.